# Equivalent of embeddings_regularizer in pyTorch

Tags: keras, pytorch

`tf.keras.layers.Embedding` has parameter `embeddings_regularizer`. What would be equivalent of this in pyTorch or `nn.Embedding`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent for PyTorch as PyTorch only supports `L2` regularization on parameters via [`torch.optim`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html) optimizers.

For example [torch.optim.SGD](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.SGD) has `weight_decay` parameter. If you set it up **and** you optimize your `nn.Embedding` it will be regularized by `L2` with specified strength (you can pass only `nn.Embedding` for `weight_decay`, see [per-parameter-options](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#per-parameter-options) of optimizers).

If you wish to use `L1` regularization you would have to:

- code it on your own
- use available third party solutions

### Coding on your own

Usually we add `L1` regularization to loss and backpropagate, but this is inefficient approach.

It is better to populate gradients of our parameters (there are some edge cases though) with the derivative of regularization (for `L1` is it sign value). Something along those lines:

```
import torch

# Do this in your optimization loop AT THE TOP
embedding = torch.nn.Embedding(150, 100)
embedding.weight.grad = torch.sign(embedding.weight)

# Do the rest of optimization AND clear gradients!
...
```

Though it is a little harder to make it work in general (stuff like batch accumulation etc.) and pretty unclear IMO. You could apply `L2` on top of that also.

### `torchlayers` third party library

**Disclaimer: I'm the author of this project**

You can install `torchlayers-nightly` and get per-layer `L1` and `L2` regularization.

Install via `pip`:

```
pip install -U torchlayers-nightly
```

In your code you could do:

```
import torchlayers as tl
import torch

embedding = torch.nn.Embedding(150, 100)
regularized_embedding = tl.L1(embedding)

# Do the rest as per usual
```

This feature is experimental for now, but should work and I've used it with success previously.

Also, you should be able to use `tl.L2` the same way, see [docstrings](https://github.com/szymonmaszke/torchlayers/blob/master/torchlayers/regularization.py#L195) about usage of this particular layer.

For more info check [github repository](https://szymonmaszke.github.io/torchlayers/) and read documentation [here](https://szymonmaszke.github.io/torchlayers/).